# Why is there a variation in the stackexchange site name between URL and title?

Tags: discussion

When I check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, the site title is mentioned as *ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING*. As for as I know, [Electronics Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_engineering) and [Electrical Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_engineering) are entirely different subjects. In our college we have Electrical and Electronics as two different departments :-P. Why are there different title and website names like this? Is this a mistake with website design or is there any reason behind this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Not the only one: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So, you'd rather it be electriceengineering.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that one. When I checked Electronics engineering I got this doubt and suddenly asked here.

Comment: And what about http://gaming.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Yes! electricalengineering.stackexchange.com or else if this site has been receiving more electronics related question we can change the title as ELECTRONICS ENGINEERING :P

Comment: A bit long for a URL, don't you think?

Comment: Yup! we are having more sites like this but my question is Electrical and Electronics are two different subjects that why asked.

Comment: Then we can change it as electriceengineering.stackexchange.com as you said your comment

Comment: Still incredibly long. My suggestion wasn't serious. And you are underestimating the impact of changing the domain name (what happens to all old links? Google rankings?).

Comment: English Language Learners site has URL as ell.stackexchange.com like that we can change it as ee.stackexchange.com or simply electrical.stackexchange.com

Comment: May I know the reason for down votes? If you hate this question please leave a comment so that I wont ask questions any more.

Comment: See also: cooking.stackexchange.com

Comment: Whatever you think "electrical engineering" is, it's on topic here. There are various ways to point out the difference between electrical engineering (the microcontroller and opamp stuff) and electric power engineering (the utility power plant stuff) across the world, but both are on topic here so it doesn't matter.  Besides, nobody is going to take the URL as a definition of what the site is about.

Comment: @OlinLathrop   "Besides, nobody is going to take the URL as a definition of what the site is about."  Except search engines.  They treat URL string a significant bit of information.  I too think that *ee* or *eee* would be an appropriate URL for us.  There are plenty of stacks with an acronym in the URL: ell, cs, dba, gis, rpg.  I could write a thorough post showing that SE was not always spot-on when it comes to naming stacks, especially when a stack is not about IT or software development.

Comment: See also: ["Is electrical suitable as a name?"](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/879/25328)

Comment: @NickAlexeev I would argue that CS, RPG, and GIS are common acronyms in the first place... but if ELL is okay, then I'd be happy with EEE or EE.

Answer (score 8):

So, a bit of history here...

[Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange has had a whole lot of different names](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/586/what-is-chiphacker/601#601).

Changing the name is easy. Changing the URL is not. Yes, we can set up redirects, but there tend to be all sorts of little gotchas, especially for established sites that don't want to wreck the ability of folks to find stuff via Google.

So at some point we stopped changing the URL.

### See also:

- [What is Chiphacker?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/586/what-is-chiphacker/601#601)
- ["Electronics and Robotics" has been renamed to "Electronics"](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/electronics-and-robotics-has-been-renamed-to-electronics)
- [ANNOUNCEMENT - Site Title Change](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/565/announcement-site-title-change)